# PHP How can I make pairs of numbers to an multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to build an array from simple matrix.

The 1st number should represent an array with some data. It should be inserted in the array represented by 2nd number (in line).

I tried many loops and array functions, but I need help.

How can I make this

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 0
3 -> 2
4 -> 1
5 -> 4
```

to

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
        [id] => 1
        [child] => Array
            (
            [] => Array
               (
               [id] => 4
               [child] => Array
                    (
                    [] => Array
                        (
                        [id] => 5
                        )
                    )
                )
             )

        )

    [] => Array
        (
        [id] => 2
        [child] => Array
                (
                [] => Array
                   (
                   [id] => 3
                   )
                )
        )

)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$in = [ 
1 => 0,
2 => 0,
3 => 2,
4 => 1,
5 => 4];

$arr = ['id' => 0];

$p = [[]];

foreach($in as $key => $val) {
   $i = &$arr;
   foreach($p[$val] as $step) $i = &$i['child'][$step];
   if (!isset($i['child'])) $i['child'] = [];
   $i['child'][] = ['id' => $key];
   $p[$key] = $p[$val];
   $p[$key][] = count($i['child'])-1;
}
```

Up here all levels have the same structure. But if you want as in question take so

```
print_r($arr['child']);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/399427)